# How do I add row values to colnames in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and I would like to add the first row to the names of the columns

What I have:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| city | state | country |
| ... | ... | ... |

What I want:

| col1_city | col2_state | col3_country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| city | state | country |
| ... | ... | ... |

I can't do it manually because there are many cols in the df

I think of something like

```
df %>% rename_with(~ names(.) %>% 
                map_chr(~glue('{.x}_.[1,])))
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With rename_with

```
df %>%
  rename_with(.cols = everything(),
              .fn   = ~paste0(colnames(df), '_', df[1,]))
```

---

Update: Here's a solution where you can pass the current data as it is created/altered within a pipe:

```
df |> 
  (\(x) (x <- x |> 
           rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                       .fn   = ~paste0(colnames(x), '_', x[1,]))))()
```

So here you could, for example, do some filtering before the renaming or some mutating or whatever you want.

Comment: can I do this within a pipe? It would be bad to break the pipeline

Comment: Yes, I have a solution in mind with the new native pipe |>, but I‘m afk, so can only test and post a solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, just do

```
names(df) <- paste0(names(df), "_", unlist(df[1,]))
```

-output

```
> df
  col1_city col2_state col3_country
1      city      state      country
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   set_names(str_c(names(.), '_', slice(., 1)))
```

-output

```
  col1_city col2_state col3_country
1      city      state      country
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = "city", col2 = "state", 
col3 = "country"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```